# javers: Identify or avoid duplicate diff results

Tags: javers

I am comparing two objects containing a list of objects,using JaVers v3.0.0. The objects I am comparing differ in the contents of the list, for example an object is removed from the list.

I am getting two change objects when I perform this comparison: one ListChange and one ObjectRemoved.

When presenting the result, I need to make sure that the same change is not presented twice. I am having a hard time figuring out how to either identify or avoid these duplicates that I am getting. I have tried using GlobalID but I end up parsing strings which does not feel entirely safe. I have also tried skipping ListChange or ObjectRemoved from my presentation, but that presents problems when I also have a ListChange of a list of values, or an ObjectRemoved for an object that is not in a list.

```
@Test
public void javersDuplicateDiffResult() {

    MyMainObj objA = new MyMainObj(Arrays.asList(new MyListedObj("hello"), new MyListedObj("world")));
    MyMainObj objB = new MyMainObj(Arrays.asList(new MyListedObj("hello")));

    Javers javers = JaversBuilder.javers()
            .withListCompareAlgorithm(ListCompareAlgorithm.LEVENSHTEIN_DISTANCE)
            .build();
    Diff res = javers.compare(objA, objB);

    System.out.println(res);

    Assert.assertEquals(1, res.getChanges().size());
}

class MyMainObj {
    private List<MyListedObj> theObjectList;

    public MyMainObj(List<MyListedObj> anObjectList) {
        this.theObjectList = anObjectList;
    }
}

class MyListedObj {
    private String theText;

    public MyListedObj(String aText) {
        this.theText = aText;
    }
}
```

Here is the output from running the example code above:

```
Diff:
1. ObjectRemoved{globalId:'org.example.TestJavers$MyMainObj/#theObjectList/1'}
2. ListChange{globalId:'org.example.TestJavers$MyMainObj/', property:'theObjectList', containerChanges:[(1).removed:'org.example.TestJavers$MyListedObj@2aece37d']}


java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expected :1
Actual   :2
```

Answer (score 0):

In JaVers, `ObjectRemoved` informs you that an object disappeared from an object graph on the left. While `ListChange->ValueRemoved` is the `PropertyChange` and informs about concrete place in the object graph where the change occurred.

These two changes concerns the same object (removed one) but are not duplicates.

For example:

```js
Class A {
  List<B> listOfB
  B bRef
}
```

If you compare:

```
def b1 = new B()
javers.compare( new A(listOfB:[b1], bRef:b1), new A(listOfB:[], bRef:null) )
```

You will have three changes:

- b1 `ObjectRemoved` (general information)
- b1 `ListChange->ValueRemoved` on `listOfB` property (specific place in the object graph)
- `ValueChanged` from b1 to null on `bRef` property (another specific place in the object graph)

What I can suggest you is simply ignoring `ObjectRemoved` changes and relying only on `PropertyChanges` (`ListChange`, `ValueChange` ...)

Comment: Only relying on `PropertyChanges` won't work for POJOs as the `ValueRemoved` will not be the content of the actual POJO removed, but will be something like `value:com.foo.bar.SomePojo/#field/0` which is useless..

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no way to achieve this in Javers. I solved a similar problem by filtering out the duplicate differences based on path of the change. Here is how

1. Identify the path of the change (List Change or Value Change)
   You will have to write code to generate the path
2. If the path is subpath path of `Object Removed` or `Value Removed` then ignore it

In your case,
Diff1: ObjectRemoved path: theObjectList/1
Diff2: ValueRemoved  path: theObjectList/1/MyListedObj@2aece37d

You can discard Diff2 because the path is a subpath of a removed object.

the ValueRemoved path is built by concatenating ListChange path with the Value Change path